# Akka.net readJournal plugin for inmem journal plugin

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

Which readJournal plugin should I use with inmem journal plugin?

```
let readJournal = mailbox.System.ReadJournalFor<????>(SqlReadJournal.Identifier)
```

I know for Akka, there is InMemoryReadJournal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently there is no Akka.Persistence.Query support for the in-memory journal but one of our contributors offered to start working on it now. I'll update my answer here when we ship something.

I'm also reviewing an Akka.Persistence.Query impl for our Sqlite implementation right now, which offers an in-memory version: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/6359

Comment: We have a draft PR implementing Akka.Persistence.Query support for the memory journal now: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/6409

Comment: Implemented now

Comment: nice work @SergeyPopov

Comment: Cool!! Akka.net is awesome!!